# How do I iterate through child objects and convert all non-object values to string

Tags: javascript, typescript

I currently have an existing method where I convert all key value pairs to string

```
export function convertObjValueToString<T>(data: Record<string, T>): Record<string, string> {
  return Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, key) => {
    return {
      ...acc,
      [key]: String(data[key]),
    };
  }, {});
}
```

but it is currently limited to the first level of an object. I want it to test deeper if for instance the value is another child object

```
{ 
    id: 2, 
    metadata: { 
        booleanValue: false, 
        someOtherKey: { 
            booleanValue: false
        }
    }
}
```

expected result would be:

```
{ 
    id: '2', 
    metadata: { 
        booleanValue: 'false', 
        someOtherKey: { 
            booleanValue: 'false'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: DO you expect your object (passed argument) to match some pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries()` to convert the object to an array of `[key, value]`, map the array of pairs and transform according to type, and then convert back to an object using `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const convertObjValueToString = data => {
  if (Array.isArray(data)) return data.map(convertObjValueToString)

  if (data !== null && typeof data === 'object') return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(data)
    .map(([k, v]) => [k, convertObjValueToString(v)])
  )

  return String(data)
}


const obj = {
  id: 2,
  metadata: {
    booleanValue: false,
    someOtherKey: {
      booleanValue: false,
      nullKey: null,
      undefinedKey: undefined,
    }
  }
}

const result = convertObjValueToString(obj)

console.log(result)
```

### Types

You'll need to use a [recursive type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#more-recursive-type-aliases) both to describe the original object, and then resulting object ([TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAchDOwIBMBqBDANgVwQHgBUA+KAXgFgAoKKAHygKpvoG8oBtMAJwHtIvQALiiIuASwB2AcwC6wuIhQYc+YlAC+TOrARI0WXPEJF2MgNxUqAYx4TEUGxIBuEAQHkARgCtluAjwBlYHFpMigACmR0YHR5XSUDfHQJECIASjjFfRUjUUkpElISFi0xADMIgEEuLnQQADoxeGrakEjo9DS0qC4IYGwuCSgomPqAW3QwcMcXd29fCH8gkKk0y2oocojQSB4KkfQyUlIoAHIebwgrYFPu3v7BqE8vK+B6st4xgFEJYLEEcJaGjPV71CC-cQAg5rDY0caTcLhdgAawANFAnDJukUOGiHLZZsBngsln9pOEnGksVoYVp7gMhst8u0YjDNBtrLZ7BcvGEShsxMhhAAmVFaMZ9dAHYT8mg0Dw8HiYCDJBbCMpYeAQMWwkQ8CVuYAAC1cAGkICAZUC5QqlSqJGqoBrMFqdXK5RJsJhMObLVBPd63e6oNgJMgIGVJChfcJQ+HIxIUEGaOyU1R2Zy7MAeggvdmTjNXET5olSStwjyYUA)):

```
type NestedValues<T> =
  | T
  | { [property: string]: NestedValues<T> }
  | NestedValues<T>[];

const convertObjValueToString = (data: NestedValues<any>): NestedValues<string> => {
  if (Array.isArray(data)) return data.map(convertObjValueToString)

  if (typeof data === 'object') return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(data)
    .map(([k, v]) => [k, convertObjValueToString(v)])
  )

  return String(data)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Would it be possible to consider `undefined` or `null` values? As I am trying to convert them into string as well

Comment: Updated to handle `null` and `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

```
export function convertObjValueToString<T extends object>(data: Record<string, T>): Record<string, string> {
  return Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, key) => {
    const currentPropValue = data[key];
    if(currentPropValue === Object(currentPropValue)) {
      return {
        ...acc,
        [key]: convertObjValueToString(currentPropValue)
      };
    }

    return {
      ...acc,
      [key]: String(data[key]),
    };
  }, {});
}
```

I got the solution right but I having problem fixing the types though as I am getting a `argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, object>'` under my if condition

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example:

```js
type Values = number | boolean | string
type Dictionary = { [prop: string]: Dictionary | Values }

const isObject = (data: unknown): data is Dictionary => 
  typeof data === 'object' && data !== null

type ObjToString<Obj extends Dictionary> = {
  [Prop in keyof Obj]:
  (Obj[Prop] extends Dictionary
    ? ObjToString<Obj[Prop]>
    : (Obj[Prop] extends Values
      ? `${Obj[Prop]}`
      : never)
  )
}

const record = <
  Key extends PropertyKey,
  Value
>(key: Key, value: Value) =>
  ({ [key]: value })

const merge = <
  Obj extends Dictionary,
  Part extends Dictionary
>(obj: Obj, part: Part) =>
  ({ ...obj, ...part })

const convert = <
  Data extends Dictionary
>(data: Data): ObjToString<Data> =>
  Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, elem) => {
    const value = data[elem];

    const maker = isObject(value) ? convert : String

    return merge(acc, record(elem, maker(value)))
  }, {} as ObjToString<Data>)


const result = convert({
  id: 2,
  metadata: {
    booleanValue1: false,
    someOtherKey: {
      booleanValue2: false
    }
  }
})

const id = result.id // `${number}`
const booleanValue2 = result.metadata.someOtherKey.booleanValue2 // "false"
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/W48avW)

`Values` - represents allowed primitive values of the object

`Dictionary` - represents allowed shape/interface of argument

`isObject` - custom typeguard. Check whether passed value is an object or not

`ObjToString` - type representation of business logic. Converts passed object to object where all primitive values are stringified

`record` - small helper (can be inlined)

`merge` - small helper (can be inlined)

`convert` - main function. Recursively goes through each key and converts value to string or makes recursive call

As you might have noticed `result` is infered and TS is aware which properties are allowed an which are not. Please keep in mind that I have passed literal value of object. If you pass a reference TS still infer allowed properties but values wll be more wider. For instance instead of `"false"` you will get `"true"|"false"`

If your argument should match some interface it is better because in that case TS will infer required properties more precisely